# How can I find out a facebook profile from an instagram picture?

Tags: facebook, server, instagram, fileserver

Using source, I have found out that

1] Instagram saves pictures in :

```
igcdn-photos-<x>-a.akamaihd.net/...
```

2] Facebook saves photos in :

```
fbcdn-photos-<y>-a.akamaihd.net/...
```

How can I use this information to get the facebook profile of an Instagram user, assuming in today's world, 90% chances of FB and Instagram profiles being linked...?

Comment: Those are just akamai CDN links. Those have nothing to do with what which user uploaded the image

Comment: Spandan, sorry to bother. You have posted about a vimeo blob issue, it has been deleted, but still is listed in google search. Did you solve that issue?

Comment: @gbvisconti: nope I didn't solve that issue. I am still looking for workarounds to that blob.

Comment: @Spandan, I think I just manage to get the download link. Mail me: it's my username at gmail.

Answer (score 5):

You can´t, and you shouldn´t. Those are different platforms (even though Instagram is owned by Facebook now). If you want to link a platform to a specific user, authorize the user on Facebook (or Instagram). You are only allowed to use the profile picture if the user allows it, so the authorization is not really a problem.